# Picasso.with() loades images, but picasso.get() the images in my listview are not showing when collecting it from Firebase Database

Tags: android, picasso

After Update picasso to use picasso.get() images from Firebase are not loading in listview

When running debug I do get the https://xxxxx link and if I copy it into browser the image shows.
Help will be appreciated in this matter. I have tried for the last week to sort this out been to so many web pages but none of them are working.All was working before the upgrade.

Also using latest  implementation:

```
implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828"
```

In Adapter using:

```
Picasso.get().load(item.getImageUrl()).resize(600, 400).into(holder.text2);
```

Comment: share picasso code where you are loading images..

Comment: `holder.text2`, is it a **ImageView** or **TextView**?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman sorry for that actually before i start comment your comment is not there. my intention was not to repeat same things. sorry.

Comment: please check this item.getImageUrl() is their any value for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
          Picasso.get()
        .load("yoururlhere")

            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
           //check exception

           }
          })
```

You can check what is wrong with Picasso by this